# Creating a javascript library with dependencies on other libraries

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, client-side, dependency-management

I'm building a client-side javascript library that can be 'imported' using requireJS or via the `<script>` tag.
During development, I realized I need such libraries as JQuery, and IndexedDBShim.

What is the correct approach for importing these? do I go for the old-copy-paste the whole minified library into my source code *(Hopefully not...)*?
I don't want to rely on the user importing these dependencies as well, and if I requireJS them in my own code, won't I depened on the customer having requireJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out [Webpack](https://webpack.github.io/). This is a bundler that will create a single file for you('more complex setup possible') with all dependencies injected to it, based on what you require.

Also check out [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/). It might be best to create a module which other people can then use.

Comment: I will be using npm to make my library available, but it doesn't solve my dependency issue. 
And my library will be a single file, so you're suggesting I should let webPack copy/paste the module into my code at buildtime?

Comment: You can add dependencies in npm. When someone downloads your module these will be installed as well. This would be the preferred method. If you want to distribute your library without npm, then I would pack everything into a single JS file with webpack. Or tell the user what other libraries to load before yours.

Comment: I will distribute via npm, but not all my dependencies work with npm, some are imported via bower.  I'm trying to avoid telling my users what to load...So there is no standardisation of this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. That is the curse of JavaScript at the moment.